# Vue directive like {% with %} at Django OR another way to get simpler name at tempate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In Python Django we have [directive {% with %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

I looking for an analog in Vue 3, but dissapointed

When I use plugins like `vue-good-table` at page's template I need use code:

```
 
<div
  v-if="props.row[props.column.field].useCounter"
  :class="`severity-${props.row[props.column.field].maxSeverity}`"
>
  <span v-if="props.row[props.column.field][lvl] !== 0">
    {{props.row[props.column.field][lvl]}}
  </span>
</div>
```

As you can see, `props.row[props.column.field]` is repeating 4 times!

Does really Vue not contain such a useful feature?

```
<div
  v-with="props.row[props.column.field] as cell"
  v-if="cell.useCounter"
  :class="`severity-${cell.maxSeverity}`"
>
  <span v-if="cell[lvl] !== 0">
    {{cell[lvl]}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean a `v-for`? And also no i cannot see that its repeating 4 times, you dont provide an additinal code

Comment: I think `v-for="(item, i) in [blablabla-longname]` is abuse of v-for directive; and we can't use v-for and v-if at same time... At realy longname repeating more than 10 times, this is small piece of additional code, and it doesn't matter what's in it, I'm just looking for such a directivу... maybe someone wrote it as a plugin?